# App store download previous version of app instead of latest

Tags: iphone, ios

I already have an app on app store with version 1.0.0.
Now I submitted the new version of app 2.0.0. This new version is also approved by apple.
It has been more than 5 days since my app is approved and in state 'Ready for sale'.

Now when I download the app from app store on my iphone device it still downloads the previous version (1.0.0) and asks me to update to latest version (2.0.0).

Why app store is not downloading the latest version (2.0.0) of app directly on my device?
My device previously had the app with version 1.0.0 installed from app store but I deleted it and then installed the fresh app from app store.

When I download the same app on my friend's iphone it downloads the latest version (2.0.0). This device never had any version of the app installed.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with an app I updated 2 weeks ago. Did you find a resolution?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and have now realised that it is related to iCloud. If you have previously downloaded your app on any device then when you download it on a new device, it will download the same version as you previously downloaded. You then get the option to update to the latest version.

Confused me to start with!

Answer (score 0):

Your iPhone could be outdated / not meeting your defined requirements of the application itself. For example, if you have an iPhone 3G running IOS 6, you can not run an app that only accepts iOS7. Take a look in your xCode and inspect the properties of your application.

Comment: Both version of my app does support iOS5.0 onwards. My iPhone is iPhone4S running iOS6.1. So I don't think this should be the reason. Does it related to cloud as app store shows cloud icon in front of my app, tapping on it installs the app on device